# How to use AddUsersToRoles Method in Asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I want to add special previlages to different users.

So i just want to use AddUsersToRoles Method in my .cs code.

i have superuser, admin, manager and employee as a dropdown list in html code.

buy using AddUsersToRoles Method how to call the dropdown list in my .cs file?

I am trying to write this code but i am getting error near ddroles(dropdown id). it is not accepting the overload i have used.

```
  Roles.AddUsersToRoles(username,ddroles);
```

Can you please help me how to use this method and how to write this overload.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some code.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error is near ddroles(dropdown ID). It is not accepting the overload i have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both parameters of [Roles.AddUsersToRoles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.adduserstoroles(v=vs.110).aspx) require arrays of string.

You will need to provide something like this -

```
string[] usernames = {"johndoe", "janetdoe"};
string[] roleNames = {"Administrators", "Customers"};
Roles.AddUsersToRoles(usernames, roleNames);
```